# image in my post disappeared after I upload website to remote server

Tags: images, uploads, media, server-load

Before I upload my website to server, I created post with images which are uploaded to media, their url are, for example: http://localhost:40952/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/study_in-En.gif

After I uploaded website to server, the link to the images in the post is not updated, therefore, the images are disappeared in post.

Is there anyway I can update the images link automatically? It is very painful to go and fix every link url. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

before copy/pasting the database from your local machine to the production server, you should do a Find & Replace on the domain name.

this way you replace `localhost:40952` with the correct domain on every url in the database.

or read the part ['Moving WordPress to a New Server'](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_to_a_New_Server) on the codex.

Comment: Thanx. Let's me try.